# Is there a way to get a YouTube Live-Stream chat via websocket

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'd prefer not to keep polling for new chat messages so I was wondering if there's a way to use PubSub and the YouTube Data API to retrieve new live-stream chat messages?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications